# "Helvetica Neue Medium" font is not working properly in browsers mainly chrome, Mozilla, IE

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have hosted the font on the server and then called it in css but its not working.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
src: url('http://serverhosted.com/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.ttf');
}
```

Also, I have used font from the local fonts folder created under the project folder.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
src: url('../fonts/HelveticaNeue-Medium.ttf');
}
```

"Helvetica Neue Regular" font is showing up properly but I want to work with "Helvetica Neue Medium" as my font family in website.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Medium'` instead;